# How do I pass in an object to a rest template?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

How do I pass in an object to a `RestTemplate`? I currently have an object that I am trying to pass in to two different functions. In one way, I want to pass it in as a `RequestBody`, and in the other I want to pass it in as a `RequestParam`.

For example, I have the following code:

```
Student student = new Student("Allison");
Teacher response = restTemplate.getForObject("url for get student's teacher api/{schoolID}", Teacher.class, student);
```

The `getStudentsTeacher` takes in paramters `(@PathVariable schoolID, @RequestBody Student student)`.

My code does not work, as I am not specifying the content type (json), so how would I do this? Also, how would this work with `@RequestParam` instead of `@RequestBody`?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [RestTemplate javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-), the uri variables can be expanded. So, all you need to do, is to supply to value to expand the variable in the template

```
Teacher response = restTemplate.getForObject("domain.com/api/{schoolId}", Teacher.class, 123);
```

Now, it's really strange that you're sending a GET request with body.
If you really need to do so, then you'll have to use the [RestTemplate#exchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) method.

```
HttpEntity<Student> request = new HttpEntity<Student>(new Student("Allison"));
// 123 -> it's the schoolId that the exchange method will be using to expand the uri variable
ResponseEntity<Teacher> teacher = restTemplate.exchange("domain.com/api/{schoolId}", HttpMethod.GET, request, Teacher.class, 123);
log.info(teacher.getBody());
```

Comment: If I want more than the student's school ID, how would i pass this information? If I have many fields from the student that I want to access for example (so that I have to pass in the student object), how can i achieve this? I looked into httpentity, but not sure if that works here

Comment: sorry, didn't saw that you need to send a body in the request. answer updated. take a look

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. So do I need to specify the http headers as json as well?

Comment: Actually, you only need to pass the object, not the string. The RestTemplate already serialize the object as json to send the request. And the headers need to be sent as specified in the example at the docs. Take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html

Comment: Sorry, which string are you referring to

Comment: The JSON string that you referred in your previous comment